# Kotlin Type Mismatch "Nothing"

Tags: kotlin, generics

Consider the following code, which has been stripped back to illustrate only the problem with generics:

```kotlin
interface Node

interface GenericNode<T : GenericNode<T>> : Node {
    val pointer: NodePtr<T>?
}

class NodePtr<T : Node>(private val value: T) {
    fun isPointingTo(other: T): Boolean {
        return value == other
    }
}

class BasicNode : Node

class GenericNodeImpl(override val pointer: NodePtr<GenericNodeImpl>) : GenericNode<GenericNodeImpl>
```

`Node` may have many implementations. Here we have `GenericNode<T : GenericNode<T>>` which contains a pointer to another `GenericNode<T : GenericNode<T>>` (consider this *sort of* like a singly-linked list mechanism), and we have `BasicNode`.

Now consider the following which demonstrates the problem:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = GenericNodeImpl(null)
    val b = GenericNodeImpl(NodePtr(a))
    val c = GenericNodeImpl(NodePtr(b))
    val d = BasicNode()

    val list: List<Node> = listOf(a, b, c, d)

    list.filterIsInstance<GenericNode<*>>().filter { it.pointer?.isPointingTo(a) ?: false }
}
```

I've declared `List<Node>` as it can contain any `Node` type, but then I want to filter any instances of type `GenericNode<*>`. I don't care about the specific implementation, or what `T` is in this case, it just has to be `GenericNode<*>`.

For each of those nodes, I want to know which ones are pointing to `a`, but `isPointingTo(a)` contains the following error:

> Type mismatch.
>
> Required: Nothing
>
> Found: GenericNodeImpl

I'm assuming that the issue is caused by filtering `GenericNode<*>` where `*` is `Unknown`, but that is unavoidable. Is there an `in` or `out` missing somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Technically `NodePtr` could be contravariant in `T` (`in T`) because it only takes a `T` as *input* (to the `isPointingTo()` method).

As a consequence, `GenericNode` could also be `in T`, because `T` is only used for the `pointer` property which is now `in T`.

That being said, it doesn't solve your problem, because your problem is conceptual. You're filtering with `GenericNode<*>`, meaning you don't know what `T` is, and `T` could really be any subtype of `GenericNode`, including `Nothing`. This means that the following `NothingGenericNode` implementation could be a potential element in the list:

```kotlin
class NothingGenericNode(override val pointer: NodePtr<Nothing>?) : GenericNode<Nothing>
```

From there, you can see that `pointer` could be of type `NodePtr<Nothing>` and thus accept 0 possible values as argument of `isPointingTo`. The compiler protects you from that. It only allows you to pass arguments that would be valid for all possible subtypes of `GenericNode`. But since there is a subtype that accepts nothing at all, then your generic code cannot pass anything either.

One solution to this problem would be to be more lenient on what `isPointingTo` accepts. For instance it could maybe accept any subtype of `Node` instead of only the specific `T`:

```kotlin
fun isPointingTo(other: Node): Boolean
```